# Use collapse and popover together in Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the badge independently from the collapse but I'm having some problems with it.

```
$(function (e) {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html: true})
})
$('.badge').click($(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
})

)
```

See the prototype bellow:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dhanck/sk269gw5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost! You don't need to wrap the 'click' handler function as a jQuery object.

Before:

```
...
$('.badge').click($(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
})
)
...
```

After:

```
...
$('.badge').click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
})
...
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sk269gw5/1/